# Axiomatisable Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let A be a set of sentences (“proper axioms”) in a first-order language L with equality. Let us write Mod(A) for the class of all models of A which respect equality. We say that a class of L-structures is axiomatisable if it is Mod(A) for some such A. It is finitely axiomatisable if A is finite. (For example, the usual set of axioms G for group theory shows that the class of all groups is finitely axiomatisable.)

Prove:
(i) The class of all finite groups is not axiomatisable.
(ii) The class of all infinite groups is axiomatisable.
(iii) The class of all infinite groups is not finitely axiomatisable.

How can I prove the above results?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @lemontree I think compactness theorem can be applied but don't know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for the first question: Let $\mathcal L$ be a language and let $T$ be *any* $\mathcal L$-theory with arbitrarily large finite models. Consider the language $\mathcal L'=\mathcal L\cup\{c_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, where every $c_n$ is a constant symbol and the $\mathcal L'$ sentences $$\varphi_n=\bigwedge\limits_{\substack{1\leq i,j\leq n \\ i\neq j}}\neg(c_i=c_j)$$

so that intuitively $\varphi_n$ is saying "there are at least $n$ different elements. Is $T\cup\{\varphi_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ finitely satisfiable? What does the compactness theorem tell you now?

Hint for the second question: Look again at the $\varphi_n$ from my first hint.

Hint for the third question: Suppose that $T$ is a finitely axiomatizable theory and that $\Gamma$ is an axiomatization of $T$. Can you show that there must be a $\Delta\subset\Gamma$, with $\Delta$ finite, such that $\Delta$ is an axiomatization of $\Gamma$? Now think again about your axiomatization from the second question.

Comment: We don't have 'satisfiable', so can't use that.

Comment: Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem could be useful? (We do have the axiom of choice)

Comment: @user24199 do you know the compactness theorem?

Comment: Yes I know the compactness thoerem

Comment: Can you state precisely which version of compactness you know then? @user24199

Comment: Let L be a first-order language, A be a set of statements in L. If every finite subset of A has a model then so does A.

Comment: Then you can replace "satisfiable" with "has a model" and "finitely satisfiable" with "every finite subset has a model" in my answer @user24199